# Vue Login with Axios Request HTTP

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http, axios

Im new at Vue and im trying to make a Request HTTP to my backend,

When i inspect in my browser, i get the access token from /login but in the api/users i get "Token is Invalid". How do i get my api/users data?

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "login",
  async created() {
    const response = await axios.get("api/users", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    });

    console.log(response);
  },

  data() {
    return {
      showError: false,
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    async EnvioLogin() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        });
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
        const status = JSON.parse(response.status);
        if (status == "200") {
          console.log(response);
          this.$router.push("intermediorotas");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.showError = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.showError = false;
        }, 3000);
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: `created` hook is run before `EnvioLogin` ... so, of course the token isn't set yet ... aslo ... what is `const status = JSON.parse(response.status);` doing!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service to make call to backend, i guess the problem is the url http://localhots:3000/api, you missed this part http://localhots:3000

```
import axios from 'axios'
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhots:3000/api',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
export default client
```

then import the service

```
import myService from './myService'
await myService.get(`/auth/login`, {})
```

Comment: I use in axios.js this: import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/';

Comment: @Guilherme then instead of http://localhots:3000 use baseURL: 'http://localhots:127.0.0.1:8000';