# Axios JWT Login Frontend Request to Backend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, jwt

I'm new at programming, im doing a frotend Login with Vue for my backend database(using JWT). But when i send "Login" with the correct email / password i get the access token from "/login" but i cant get the user from "/users".

When i inspect in my browser i get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBJK0.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWQEG.jpg

This is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "login",


  data() {
    return {
      showError: false,
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
     async created() {
    const response = await axios.get("api/users", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    });

    console.log(response);
  },

  methods: {
    async EnvioLogin() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        });
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
        const status = JSON.parse(response.status);
        if (status == "200") {
          console.log(response);
          this.$router.push("intermediorotas");
          this.showLogin = false;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.showError = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.showError = false;
        }, 2000);
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: looks like the same problem as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65030100/vue-login-with-axios-request-http) - and you're still doing `const status = JSON.parse(response.status);`

Comment: your `created` hook will run before the user even attempts to login, so, of course the `token` will be invalid - as I mentioned about 17 hours ago the last time you asked

Comment: without the const status = JSON.parse(response.status); i cant get the if status ==200 when i login

Comment: How can i run created hook after the login attempts?

Comment: `response.status` is 200 (or whatever) - you're effectively doing`const status = JSON.parse(200)` ... just `const {status} = responsel` will do - that's not your issue, I've already told you what that is - you dont' understand vue component lifecycle hooks ... you don't choose when to run them, they run a the appropriate times ... the simple solution is to NOT have that code in `created()` ... have that code in some `method` you call inside `if (status == "200") {` ... or just MOVE that code into there

Comment: Thank you Bravo, i did both things. Sorry for the trouble, im new at Vue/Programming. I will study "vue component lifecycle hooks". Thank you!